# Racket - Macro - Define Function

Tags: macros, racket, function-definition

So, I'm looking to make a macro that will make it easier to write functions that take an s-expression and a list as input and do something when one of the s-expressions in the list matches the s-expression in the input. I noticed that many of these functions have the same appearance.

So, I wrote this:

```
(define-syntax (ember stx)
  (syntax-parse stx
    [(ember name terminal match recurse) #'(define name (lambda (s l)
                                                          (cond
                                                            [(null? l) terminal]
                                                            [(eq? (car l) s) match]
                                                            [else recurse])))]))

(ember member #f #t (match s (cdr l)))
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work because s is an unbound identifier. I tried to wrap it in a quote and then place an eval in the macro but that also resulted in an unbound identifier.

So, I re-wrote my code as the following and it works:

```
(define-syntax (ember stx)
  (syntax-parse stx
    [(ember name terminal match recurse) #'(define name (lambda (s l)
                                                          (cond
                                                            [(null? l) (terminal s l)]
                                                            [(eq? (car l) s) (match s l)]
                                                            [else (recurse s l)])))]))

(ember member (lambda (x y) #f) (lambda (x y) #t) (lambda (x y) (match x (cdr y))))
```

But, unfortunately if my match definition becomes that complicated, it seems easier just to copy the member function and make new functions of the same kind by editing the places where the terminal, match and recurse options go by hand.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot take `s` and `l` out of thin air but make sure they are the same as from your input. This does that:

```
(define-syntax (ember stx)
  (syntax-parse stx
    [(ember name terminal match recurse)
     (with-syntax ([s (datum->syntax stx 's)]
                   [l (datum->syntax stx 'l)])
       #'(define name (lambda (s l)
                        (cond
                          [(null? l) terminal]
                          [(eq? (car l) s) match]
                          [else recurse]))))]))

(ember member2 #f l (member2 s (cdr l)))
(member2 'a '(1 2 a 3))
; ==> (a 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use [Syntax Parameters](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/stxparam.html) instead of datum->syntax:

```
(define-syntax-parameter s (syntax-rules ()))
(define-syntax-parameter l (syntax-rules ()))

(define-syntax-rule
  (ember name terminal match recurse)
  (define name
    (lambda (s* l*)
      (syntax-parameterize ([s (make-rename-transformer #'s*)]
                            [l (make-rename-transformer #'l*)])
        (cond
          [(null? l) terminal]
          [(eq? (car l) s) match]
          [else recurse])))))

(ember member #f l (member s (cdr l)))
(member 'a '(1 2 a 3))
; -> '(a 3)
```

See [Keeping it Clean with Syntax Parameters](http://www.schemeworkshop.org/2011/papers/Barzilay2011.pdf) for details as to why.